# gnu make - what is $(hide)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm looking at existing makefiles and I see `$(hide)` but on the [GNU Make docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), `hide` does not appear a single time.

What is `$(hide)`?

Comment: It's a reference to a make variable with the name `hide`.  Just like `$(CC)` is a reference to a make variable with the name `CC`.

Comment: @MadScientist so it's not a make command?

Comment: See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference

Comment: You can try and look for a line which looks like `hide = ` or `hide :=` etc. to find its definition.

Comment: It is not a make command.

Comment: It can be anything, but most of the time when I see/use it it just expands to `@`, which then hides the command executed on this line.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you meaning makefile(.mk) in Android building system.
Here's a [older link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/b1a60f32cc6b482c1209e1d53e773add926dc520/build/core/definitions.mk) that describe the usage.
By default, the $(hide) macro will hides the command executed on its line, if you want show command, set $(hide) to empty.